# ¿Cómo guardo y edito los datos del paciente?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Estoy usando php pero creo que mi problema está en los archivos js. Intento crear un nuevo paciente y tambien modificarlo pero al rellenar el formulario siempre me salta mi caja de dialogo de que ya existe ese paciente en ambos casos. Ni en la consola ni en la terminal me arrojan algun tipo de error, asi que no sé qué está pasando.

Este es el codigo de editar el paciente:

```
    const id = getParamsUrl('id');
    const historial = getParamsUrl('historial');
    var cedula_actual ='';
    var option_paises = '';
    $.get("controller/pacientes/pacientes-back.php", 
    {"oper":"get_paciente","id":id},function(response){
    $("#cedula").val(response.cedula);
    cedula_actual =response.cedula;
    $("#nombre").val(response.nombre);
    $("#fecha-nacimiento").val(response.fecha_nacimiento);
    //$("#sexo").val(response.sexo);
    $('input[type="radio"][name="sexo"][value="'+response.sexo+'"]').click();

    $("#telefono").val(response.telefono);
    $("#correo").val(response.correo);
    },"json")

    $('#fecha-nacimiento').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "showDropdowns": true,
    "minDate": '1900-01-01',
    "locale": {
    "maxDate": new Date(),
    "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "separator": " al ",
    "applyLabel": "Seleccionar",
    "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
    "fromLabel": "Desde", 
    "toLabel": "Hasta",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "Dom",
        "Lun",
        "Mar",
        "Mie",
        "Jue",
        "Vie",
        "Sab"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
        "Enero",
        "Febrero",
        "Marzo",
        "Abril",
        "Mayo",
        "Junio",
        "Julio",
        "Agosto",
        "Septiembre",
        "Octubre",
        "Noviembre",
        "Diciembre"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1
      }
    });
    // validación de cedula
    $('#cedula').blur(function(){
    let cedula = $(this).val();  
    if(cedula != '' && cedula != cedula_actual){  
    $.get("controller/pacientes/pacientes-back.php",{ 'oper' : 
    'buscarCedula','cedula' : cedula},
    function(response) {    
            if(response.error){
                swal("Error!",response.mensaje,"error");
                $('#cedula').val(cedula_actual);
                $('#cedula').focus();
            }else{
                toastrSuccess(response.mensaje,'');
            }
    },"json");
   }
   });


   // GUARDAR
    $("#boton-guardar").on('click',function(){
    $("#overlay").show();

    if(mandatorio("div-paciente") == 1){
    let cedula = $("#cedula").val();
    let nombre = $("#nombre").val();
    let fecha_nacimiento = $("#fecha-nacimiento").val();
    let sexo = $('input:radio[name=sexo]:checked').val();
    let tipo_de_sangre = $("tipo_de_sangre").val()
    let telefono = $("#telefono").val();
    let correo = $("#correo").val();
    
    $.get('controller/pacientes/pacientes-back.php?oper=check_cedula_editar',{
        cedula: cedula,
        id: id,
    }, function(respuesta){
        if(respuesta == 1){
            $.post("controller/pacientes/pacientes-back.php",{
                "oper" : "editar_paciente",
                "id_paciente": id,
                "cedula": cedula,
                "nombre": nombre,
                "fecha_nacimiento": fecha_nacimiento,
                "telefono": telefono,
                "correo": correo,
                "sexo": sexo,
                "tipo_de_sangre": tipo_de_sangre
            },function(response){
                $("#overlay").hide();

                if(!response.error){
                    $.when(swal("Buen trabajo!",response.mensaje,"success")).done(function(){
                        location.href="pacientes.php";
                    });
                }else{
                    swal("Error!",response.mensaje,"error");    
                }
            },"json");
        }else{
            $("#overlay").hide();
            swal('Error','Ya existe un paciente con la misma identificacion','error');
        }
    });
}else{
    $("#overlay").hide();
}
    });
```

Si yo elimino la parte final del codigo que es:

```
    else{
            $("#overlay").hide();
            swal('Error','Ya existe un paciente con la misma identificacion','error');
        }
    });
}else{
    $("#overlay").hide();
}
    });
```

Entonces se quedará atascado cargando para siempre.

El codigo para hacer nuevos clientes es similar claro con la diferencia de que es llenar un formulario vacio que guardará a la base de datos, pero reitero, no importa qué es lo que rellene me va a salir el mismo mensaje de error por default de que ya existe ese paciente

Comment: Nadie me va a ayudar?... ok... me quedé sin empleo entonces...

Comment: No esperes respuesta instántanea, ya que la gente que responde lo hace por que quiere sin cobrar de ello

Comment: ¡Mil disculpas por no ayudarte! ¿cuántas respuestas escribiste tú en esas 3:15 horas que tan pacientemente estuviste esperando a que alguien más te ayudara?

Comment: Te voy a decir porque yo no respondí: 1) Porque el código no está correctamente tabulado, entonces no se entiende.- 2) Porque a simple vista se ve que hay mucho código que sobra en la pregunta, debes colocar un [MRE] donde se vea lo mínimo necesario, por ejemplo hay unas cosas con fechas que no tienen sentido en la pregunta.- 3) Usas librerías que no aportan a la pregunta, por ejemplo swal y toastrSuccess se pueden reemplazar por un `alert`.- 4) El servidor retorna algo pero tampoco indicas que recibes como retorno ni agregas un código PHP que también tiene que cumplir con el [MRE]

Comment: Revisa en `PHP` que datos te están llegando antes de hacer la validación, por ejemplo, usando `print_r[$_GET]; die;` podrás ver estos datos en las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador. También puedes mostrar el query si es que lo tienes en una variable `print_r[$sql]; die;` y así determinas que es lo que está saliendo mal del lado del servidor. Si todo eso está bien, entonces puedes depurar el código del lado del cliente haciendo `console.log(variable)`. En conclusión, tu problema se soluciona depurando el código en tu proyecto.